# Using define() for website Name

Tags: php, forms

I have a page with a form like so:

```
        <form method="POST" action="scripts/save-settings2.php">
            <div id="posts">
                <div class="post">
                    <div>
                        <label for="siteName">Site Name</label>
                        <div class="input-wrap">
                            <input value="<?php echo constant('siteName'); ?>" type="text" name="siteName" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
                    <a href="posts.php" class="cancel">Cancel</a>
                </div>  <!--Post--> 
            </div>  <!--Posts-->    
        </form>
```

The values of the inputs are sent to this script:

```
include '../includes/database-login.php';
if (isset($_POST['siteName'])) {
$siteName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['siteName']);
define("siteName", "$siteName");
header('Location: ../settings.php');
} else {
header( 'Location: ../newpost-error.php' );
}
```

What I am trying to do is take what the users fills into the siteName input field, and define it as the constant "siteName" so I can echo the constant elsewhere on the site. For some reason this isn't working. Have I made some obvious mistake here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe the constant will stay if you change page.

Comment: I think the page changing is the problem

Answer (score 2):

defines only last the life of the script execution, they will not last through a redirect

have a look at sessions, and storing the site name in a session

```
// store in session
$_SESSION['siteName'] = $siteName;

// retrieve from session
$siteName = $_SESSION['siteName']';
```

Comment: Given the subject matter session storage does not seem very appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
define("siteName", "$siteName");
```

To this:

```
define("siteName", $siteName);
```

It will be better to set siteName upper case, and if you want to cho the content of the constant do this:

```
echo siteName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Constants in programming should only really be used for things which are known before the execution even begins and which will never change. Like this typical example:

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'database_name_here');
/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'username_here');
/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here');
```

Don't use constants for user input. And constants should always use `THE_ALL_CAPS_NAMING_SCHEME`.

If you really just want to use a variable all over your application you can use a [super global](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php).

Also constants just like variables are only stored in memory while your program executes - as soon as the execution is finished the values disappear.

If you want to use a value in multiple requests you would either store it in a database, a cache mechanism like Memcached or Redis or session storage. Note that the session relies on cookies in the browser and is [vulnerable to many kinds of hacks](http://packetcode.com/article/preventing-session-hijacking-in-php).

If you are building a content management system than you should be saving this data in the database - not in the session as recommended by some of the other answers. As the session is a kind of personal storage and will not be the same for different users.

Additionally don't use `mysql_real_escape_string` it [does not properly prevent SQL injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) when used to sanitize database input and does not prevent XSS attacks where users inject malicious javascript into the page.

- [How to prevent XSS with HTML/PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php)
- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)